# Flutter "ftpconnect" Not working not working properly when uploading an image

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have an app that uploading image to ftp server using this code :

```
  try {
    File fileToUpload = File(filePathPharmacy);

    await ftpConnect.connect();
    await ftpConnect.changeDirectory(
        "/public_html/XXXXXX/XXXXXX/main/assets/userImags");

    bool res =
        await ftpConnect.uploadFileWithRetry(fileToUpload, pRetryCount: 3);
    await ftpConnect.disconnect();
    print(res);
  } catch (w) {
    print("error : $w");
  }
```

Explain :

```
filePathPharmacy => Is the Path of the file . Example :- /data/user/0/come.adeeb.smartbureau/app_flutter/b2042f2e-bd9e-4d91-8775-7b8e26d124886989878843844875758.jpg

XXXXXX => is my location on the server (I hade it for security)
```

it is working ! and I can find the file on the FTP Server !

But the image resolution is bad or it suffers from strange distortions !

[image]

any idea to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Put the following command before

```
bool res =await ftpConnect.uploadFileWithRetry(fileToUpload, pRetryCount: 3);
```

Command:

```
await ftpConnect.sendCustomCommand('TYPE I');
```

Comment: it's so confusing, this command is not described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

we should use 'TYPE A' for text-based files and 'Type I' for byte mode (binary mode) files such as image files, depending on the type of file we want to send and receive.
you can use this command before uploading your file.

```
await ftpConnect.sendCustomCommand('TYPE I');
```

this command is not documented in pub.dev page of the package, but it's available in the source code, you can find this problem as an open issue in the repository of this package.
https://github.com/salim-lachdhaf/dartFTP/issues/21#issuecomment-1646888832